# Catch login and join group event in Kafka consumer

Tags: spring, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am building Spring application for consume data from kafka. It successfully gets messages through @KafkaListener methods and I can receive some events by adding

```
@EventListener
public void handleKafkaConsumerEvent(KafkaEvent event) {
   log.info("Kafka event " + event.toString())
}
```

But now I want to receive events about login (in log file it is like "*o.a.k.c.s.authenticator.AbstractLogin    : Successfully logged in.*" records) and (re)join to group events (in log file it is like "*o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=test_app] (Re-)joining group*") events.

Is it possible to catch that events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; those log entries are made by the `kafka-clients` directly, and are not related to Spring, so Spring can't generate events for them.